# how to set loader in center of the screen and lock screen till getting response. in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, response, loader

I am new to react native. I am trying to show loader till getting response from server. and when loader is showing I want to lock screen means user unable to scroll or unable to do anything.
here is loader code

```
import {ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native

 isLoading: true,

 <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, height: Dimensions.get('window').height / 1.1,}}>

  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        {this.state.isLoading && <ActivityIndicator  size="large" color={"orange"} />}
      </View>

</ScrollView>
```

please help thanks. By adding this code. I am not able show that loader on center and when I scroll down then This loader goes up and not showable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import {ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native

 if(isLoading){
     <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" 
      }}>
        <ActivityIndicator  size="large" color={"orange"} />
     </View>
}
else {
    <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, height: Dimensions.get('window').height / 1.1,}}>

   /* your rest code * /

  </ScrollView>
}
```

Comment: might be some issue of ScrollView which causing this problem.

Comment: i am not able to put if statment in return

Comment: you don't have to do that... you can put in render(){ }

Comment: FYR : 

   if (this.state.isLoading l) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.loading}>
          <ActivityIndicator size={"large"} color="#ee5f73" />
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (<ScrollView></ScrollView>)
}

Comment: text string must be render within <Text> component